# how to download filled up form in pdf format in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, pdf

I have a request form for leave. What the user wants is when someone fills up the form and saves it, apart from saving the form the form needs to be downloaded as pdf.

I tried to convert filled up form to pdf but to no avail. The data in form isn't visible during pdf download. So, currently I think the best way is to create another form and ng-bind the input values. When user clicks save and download, download the form with ng-bind.

Is this the only best solution or is there another way round ?

Comment: can you give a fiddle for what you have tried or paste your working code for reference

Comment: @Joyson .. I am currently trying the best way I think is the solution. Is that the best solution or there is another way round ?

Comment: Currently i have using mpdf for pdf conversion i have using the $_POST data to convert the needed data in to the pdf.

Comment: @samjhanajoshi did you try `jspdf`

Comment: @manish .. I will be trying this.